# Symfony2 - Logging not working on Production

Tags: php, logging, symfony, production

I have a Symfony2 web application.

Everything works well in local. But when moving to production environment, there are some things that don't work the same as local.

Now, to figure out what is going on on Production I am trying to write some logs.

For some reason, I am not getting to write anything to the production log. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? This is my code in the Controller in (nothing too sophisticated, by the way):

```
$logger = $this -> get("logger");
$logger -> err("My Trace --> " . $my_inspect_variable);
```

The ./logs/prod.log is being writing properly by Symfony. But when I try to write something by myself, it just ignores me.

My `config_prod.yml` file:

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler:      nested
    nested:
        type:  stream
        path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
        level: debug
```

Comment: As for the writing, log directory might not have enough privileges

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I said, Symfony engine is writing properly in the file. I can even see the CRITICAL error specified in it. The problem comes when I try to write something by myself using the container logger.

Comment: Nothing in particular... just new in PHP programming. I'll take them out if you tell me it is not too conventional. The whole rest of the application woks fine, though, so I don't think that is the cause of my problem. Thanks!